# Proof of equal segments in a cyclic quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, contest-math

Let $ABCD$ is a cyclic quadrilateral in circle $\omega$ with center $O,$ where $M$ and $N$ are the midpoints of $BC$ and $CD.$ Plot the points $E$ and $F$ on $AB$ and $AD$ respectively such that $O$ is the midpoint of $EF.$ Let $P$ be the intersection of lines $EN$ and $FM,$ and $W$ be the circumcenter of $\triangle PEF.$ If $OWPC$ is a parallelogram, and line $PZ$ intersects $AD$ and $BA$ at $Z$ and $R$ respectively, prove that $AZ=AR.$

So far, I have tried drawing a diagram. However, from the diagram, I can't find anything useful. All I can notice is that it looks like $AZ=AR.$ I would appreaciate a headstart on this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: May I have a start?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... Show a little patience. :) Community members are here in their free time and on their own schedules, which may-or-may-not align with yours. Plus, Math.SE gets a *lot* of traffic. ... In the meantime, you could edit your question to include useful context. For instance, if this is a textbook exercise, what topic(s) and technique(s) were covered in the chapter? If a contest or challenge, what's the audience? This information can help answerers help you without explaining things you already understand or using techniques beyond your skill level.

Comment: Okay! Thank you :)

Comment: What’s the source of the problem?

Comment: @StarLight Have you thought of any conditions which will make $OWPC$ a parallelogram? I made the figure in GeoGebra, but I haven't been able to make it a parallelogram

Comment: @Dr.Mathva I am sorry, but I do not know the original source of the problem. However, it is olympiad geometry, and I've seen some British Math Olympiad problems which have a similar style as it.

Comment: GeoGebra doesn't seem to want OWPC to be a parallelogram.

Comment: A drawing could help. What is this PZ?

Comment: @Dr.Mathva I have recently found out the original source of this problem. It is China TST 2019/4/1. I found a video on youtube that helped me with this problem.